# AngularJS: ui-select bind data back to the select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular js 1.3.4 version and using ui-select.

I am binding complex multilevel JSON array of objects to this ui-select which works fine. So the user can select any options in this select. When the user saves other data and this select data I am saving this info in the database. All this works fine.

What I am having issues is how to bind back data to this. It might not be the issue  of ui-select only as I am not able to bind back the data to the textbox as well.

So below is the json(after some modification) which I get from my db:

```
{
   "input1":{
      "set1":{
         "source":"uat1",
         "value":"value1"
      },
      "set2":{
         "source":"uat",
         "value":"value2",
         "options":[
            {
               "name":"option1"
            },
            {
               "name":"option2"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "input2":{
      "set3":{
         "source":"uat1",
         "value":"value3"
      },
      "set4":{
         "source":"uat",
         "value":"value4",
         "options":[
            {
               "name":"option3"
            },
            {
               "name":"option4"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Below is my directive where I try to bind back the data:

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(name, set) in sets">
    <label>{{name}}</label>
    <ui-select name="{{inputName + $index}}" ng-model="set.value" theme="bootstrap" ng-if="set.source == 'uat'">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Set">{{set.value.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="ds in set.options | filter: $select.search track by $index">
            <div ng-bind-html="ds.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>       
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <input type="text" ng-if="set.source == 'uat1'" name="{{inputName + $index}}" ng-model="set.value" />
</div>
```

The result of above is that for my ui-select I can see the options which means it is binded correctly with my incoming json data.
The issue is the value displayed. I cannot see anything select in my ui-select and my textbox is also empty.

Since the model of each of above is ng-model = 'set.value' I am passing this in my json. So I thought this would work but it does not.

I believe I am missing something in my Json. Can anyone point out whats missing here so that I can see the value field in my json to the corresponding control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS `ui-select`, the `ui-select-match` directive is used to show which value is selected and should display in the textbox. You are displaying the wrong data here (`set.value.name`). You need to instead display the selected value using `$select.selected.name`.

```html
<ui-select-match placeholder="Set">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
```

Your `ui-select-choices` are objects so if you want to set a default value from the controller, your value needs to be an object that exists in the options. So you can set a default value to the `ui-select` by assigning the right value to your `ng-model` `set.value`.

```js
"value": {
    "name":"option1"
}
```